# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1960)

Tags: java

I have the class Racer :

```
public class Racer {

private String name;
private String team;
private String result;


public Racer(String name, String team) {
    this.name = name;
    this.team = team;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Racer{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", team='" + team + '\'' +
            ", result='" + result + '\'' +
            '}';
}}
```

Then, I tried to create racer of this class in another Class :

```
public class RacerList {
public void createListOfRacers() {
Racer Kevin = createRacer("KMH_Kevin Magnussen_HAAS FERRARI");
}
```

And such methods to help creating racer :

```
 private Racer createRacer(String line) {
    return new Racer(extractNameOfTheRacer(line), extractTeamOfTheRacer(line));
}

private String extractNameOfTheRacer(String line) {
    return line.substring(line.indexOf('_' + 1), line.lastIndexOf('_'));
}

private String extractTeamOfTheRacer(String line) {
    return line.substring(line.lastIndexOf('_' + 1));
}
```

}

I received indicated Error here :

```
return line.substring(line.indexOf('_' + 1), line.lastIndexOf('_'));
```

in the method "extractNameOfRacer".

Comment: Given the input `KMH_Kevin Magnussen_HAAS FERRARI`, what is the name and what is the team?

Comment: Kevin Magnussen - name,
HAAS FERRARI - team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting index of `'_'+1` of the string which is evaluate to `96` as int which is bigger than your actual string length. Change this line

```
line.substring(line.indexOf('_' + 1), line.lastIndexOf('_'));
```

to

```
line.substring(line.indexOf('_') +1, line.lastIndexOf('_'));
```

to get the string between first underscore and last underscore

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I would recommend that you just use `String#split` here and make your life easy:

```
private Racer createRacer(String line) {
    return new Racer(line.split("_")[1], line.split("_")[2]);
}
```

The cause of your current issue is that you aren't using `substring` properly.  But, I would avoid it entirely and use `split` instead.